# Calling Javascript On PageListPager MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, paging

I want to call below mention javascript on paging i.e PageListPager which is on my view page

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    (document).on('click', 'a', function someFunction() {
        alert("ok")
        document.getElementById('page').value = cnt;
        $("#testStartedForm").submit();
    });


</script>



<div class="pagedList">
       @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("TestStarted", "Student", new { page,TestId = ViewBag.TestId,onclick="someFunction(" + page + ")" }), PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId="results",HttpMethod="POST"}))
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cant do it that way (your trying to pass `"someFunction(" + page + ")"` to a parameter on the controller named `onclick`).  You could subscribe to the `click` event of the `<a>` tags. For example

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function() {
  // do something
});
```

but you should change `document` to a selector which is the closest parent of the relevant `<a>` tags