# Submit Form on Action Link MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views, form-submit

Below mention is my view page and its a partial view i want to submit form values on my action link of view page i.e i want to  call post mentod of the controller i have written `javascript` for form submit but **its not working**

```
@model IPagedList<EAssessmentNew.Models.Question>
@using PagedList
@using PagedList.Mvc



<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function someFunction() {
        alert("ok")
        document.getElementById('page').value = cnt;
        $("#testStartedForm").submit();
        return false;
    }

</script>






@using (Html.BeginForm("TestStarted", "Student", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "testStartedForm" }))
{

    //<span>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model[0].Question_Id,abc, "Select Course", new { id = "ddlCourse", @class = "dropDown", style = "margin-left:17px;"})</span>



    if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
    {
           <input type="hidden" value="@Model[0].TestId" name="TestId"/>
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <div>
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].TestId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].QuestionId)
                 @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].QuestionTypeId)
                <span class="ResLabels">@Model[i].QuestionName</span>


                @if (Model[i].QuestionTypeId == 1)
                {
                    <div>
                        <br />
                        @for (int j = 0; j < Model[i].Options.Count(); j++)
                        {

                            <div>                  

                                     @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model[i].SelectedOption, Model[i].Options[j].OptionId)

                                <span class="Options">@Model[i].Options[j].OptionName</span>

                            </div>
                             <br />
                        }

                    </div>
                }
                else
                {

                    <div>
                         <br />
                        @for (int j = 0; j < Model[i].Options.Count(); j++)
                        {

                              <div>     

                                      @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model[i].Options[j].IsChecked, new { id = "selectedOption" + (j + 1) })
                                      @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Options[j].OptionId)




                                 <span class="Options">@Model[i].Options[j].OptionName</span>

                      </div>
                             <br />
                        }
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        }
    }


}


<div class="pagedList">
       @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("TestPaging", "Student", new { page, TestId = ViewBag.TestId,Model[0].Question_Id,Model[0].SelectedOption, @onclick = "someFunction("+ page +");" }), PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "results", HttpMethod = "POST" }))
     </div>
```

Here `PagedListPager` is my action link i want to call Post method on this particular link

Comment: Duplicate of [Calling Javascript On PageListPager MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25500261/calling-javascript-on-pagelistpager-mvc/25500979#25500979)

Comment: i dint get u what u r saying..?

Comment: Click the link and read the question and answer

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
   
    $(document).on('click', 'a', function () {
        alert("ok");
       $("#testStartedForm").submit();
       return false;
   });

</script>

Comment: i did this my form gets submitted by it gets refreshed and redirects me to first i dont want that i want to be on the same page without page gets refreshed

Comment: Sorry, I cant understand your comment. The point of the link was to show you that cant call a javascript function the way you tried. Since you are specifying `EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing` which does a submit, why do you need javascript to do another submit?

Comment: it submits but does not call for post method on controller i want to call the post method

Comment: OK, I think I now understand - using the previous link `$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); $("#testStartedForm").submit();});`

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139443/is-there-an-mvc-pager-that-uses-post-instead-of-get) may also help

Comment: no u r still not getting my point i want to fire get as well as post event on same page each time the new page is called and paging is done using MVC paging